# Obtener GCLID en dos Campos GCLID de diferentes formularios

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos formularios y en cada uno tengo un input escondido con el mismo id pero diferente name, donde se captura el gclid de adwords mediante un script, mi pregunta porque cuando el usuario envia la info desde el 2 formulario no me captura el gclid?.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookie(name, value, days){
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000)); 
var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires;
}
function getParam(p){
var match = RegExp('[?&]' + p + '=([^&]*)').exec(window.location.search);
return match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
var gclid = getParam('gclid');
if(gclid){
var gclsrc = getParam('gclsrc');
if(!gclsrc || gclsrc.indexOf('aw') !== -1){
    setCookie('gclid', gclid, 90);
}
}
</script>
<script> 
function readCookie(name) { 
  var n = name + "="; 
  var cookie = document.cookie.split(';'); 
  for(var i=0;i < cookie.length;i++) {      
  var c = cookie[i];      
  while (c.charAt(0)==' '){c = c.substring(1,c.length);}      
  if (c.indexOf(n) == 0){return c.substring(n.length,c.length);} 
  } 
  return null; 
  } 

  window.onload = function() {      
  document.getElementById('gclid_field').value = 
  readCookie('gclid'); 
  } 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que he hecho a sido cambiar el id el segundo input por gclid2 y en el script donde asignamos el gclid a los input he añadido la siguiente linea.

```
document.getElementById('gclid_field2').value = 
readCookie('gclid');
```

Donde `gclid_field2` es el id del segundo input.

Answer (score 0):

La idea de usar id es que estos deben ser únicos para cada página. Si tienes dos id con el mismo nombre, solo uno será tomado en cuenta cuando intentes obtenerlo.  Si quieres usar nombres repetidos usa una clase, por ejemplo:

var elemento1 = document.getElementsByClassName('myclass')[0];

Comment: vale y puedo en el script poner dos ID diferentes y cambiar su id en el input?